# 4 Hours of Layover at Doha International Airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, layovers, doha

I have two separate PNR's.

1st is from Delhi to Doha in Vistara Airways &
2nd is from Doha to Belgrade in Pegasus Airlines.

There are 4-5 Hours of Layover time in between these two airlines.

I am travelling with only hand baggage.

Do I need to Get Transit Visa for Qatar or Do i need to go through passport control?
How I will get Boarding Passes for 2nd Airlines at Doha Airport?

Comment: Note the risk you're taking - if your flight from Delhi is delayed by a few hours, you'll miss your flight to Belgrade. Pegasus will likely cancel your ticket.

Comment: True, but 4-5 hours is pretty healthy safety cushion, especially if you don't check luggage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That details depend a lot on whether you can get an online boarding pass from Pegasus.

As a transferring passenger, the first thing you do in Doha is to clear security again before you can get enter the main terminal area. I don't recall what documents they check at this point but it is likely that you will need a boarding pass at this time. Once you are through security  you can just walk to your gate.

If you don't have a boarding pass, you will have to go through immigration and customs, enter Qatar and go to the Pegasus check in counter.

I would call Pegasus and ask. Unfortunately these days check-in procedures are fairly unpredictable depending on what Covid document checks are required and who will do them when and where. Most airlines can do doc checks at both the check in counter and the gate, but in Doha you may not be able to get to the gate without a boarding pass.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Indian citizenship

Qatar allows visa-free 30-days to the country for Indian, so, assuming you're respecting the [COVID regulations](https://covid19.moph.gov.qa/EN/travel-and-return-policy/Pages/default.aspx#visitors), you don't need a visa (you can't qualify for transit Visa as :

- You're not flying Qatar Airways
- You need to leave the international area of the airport to check in to your next flight)